# Formatting month abbreviations using as.Date

Tags: r, date, gsub

I'm working with monthly data and have a character vector of dates, formatted:

```
Sep/2012
Aug/2012
Jul/2012
```

and so on, back to 1981. I've tried using

```
as.Date(dates, "%b/%Y")
```

where `%b` represents month abbreviations, but this only returns NAs. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I already found a workaround using `gsub()` to add "01/" in front of each entry, like so:

```
01/Sep/2012
01/Aug/2012
01/Jul/2012
```

Then `as.Dates()` works, but this seems a little inelegant, and isn't strictly accurate anyway.

Comment: Technically speaking, a month and a year do not specify a date, which is why this happens. I believe the **zoo** package has some functions for handling monthly data without days.

Comment: Good point and noted for the future - I think the **zoo** package is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for `as.yearmon()` in the **zoo** package. Given your dates

```
dates <- c("Sep/2012","Aug/2012","Jul/2012")
```

we load the package and convert to the `"yearmon"` class

```
require(zoo)
dates1 <- as.yearmon(dates, format = "%b/%Y")
dates1
```

Which gives

```
R> dates1
[1] "Sep 2012" "Aug 2012" "Jul 2012"
```

You can coerce to an object of class `"Date"` using the `as.Date()` method

```
R> as.Date(dates1)
[1] "2012-09-01" "2012-08-01" "2012-07-01"
```

Which would be a simpler way of getting the thing you did via `gsub()`. There is a `frac` argument which controls how far through the month the day component should be:

```
R> as.Date(dates1, frac = 0.5)
[1] "2012-09-15" "2012-08-16" "2012-07-16"
```

But that may ont be sufficient for you.

If you really only want the dates stored as you have them, then they aren't really dates but if you are happy to work within the **zoo** package then the `"yearmon"` class can be used as an index for a `zoo` object which is a time series.

Comment: Really excellent answer, thanks for going into detail.

Comment: wonderful answer!! I was struggling after using zoo and tsibble to change to yearmon which lubridate won’t accept anymore as a 3 letter month to switch formats. This is much straight forward. Thanks