# as.yearmon(dates, format = "%b/%Y") return NAs

Tags: r, lubridate, zoo

I have run this code in RStudio:

```
library(zoo)
dates <- c("Sep/2012", "Aug/2012", "Jul/2012")
dates1 <- as.yearmon(dates, format="%b/%Y")
dates1
```

But it returns `NA`s:

```
[1] NA NA NA
```

I'm wondering why this is happening? In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386091/formatting-month-abbreviations-using-as-date), it seems that this code returns normal results. Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps a locale issue? Parsing month abbreviations is locale dependent.

Comment: About the locale issue: [strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

Comment: After I added `loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`, problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the locale to English as mentioned in the comments or else use the built-in `month.abb` vector which is always in English regardless of locale.

Regarding the second alternative, use `read.table` to create a two column data frame from `dates` and then match the month column, `V1`, against `month.abb` to get the corresponding month number, paste that back together with the year, `V2`, and pass that to `as.yearmon`

```
library(zoo)

dates |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = "/") |>
  with(paste(V2, match(V1, month.abb), sep = "-")) |>
  as.yearmon()
## [1] "Sep 2012" "Aug 2012" "Jul 2012"
```

or slightly shorter using `gsubfn` which matches the first 3 characters and replaces that with the output of the function given in formula notation in its second argument.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(zoo)

dates |>
  gsubfn("^...", x ~ match(x, month.abb), x = _) |>
  as.yearmon("%m/%Y")
## [1] "Sep 2012" "Aug 2012" "Jul 2012"
```